# When reordering a UITableView, NSFetchedResultsController doesn't have latest state

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `UITableView` powered by an `NSFetchedResultsController` and am trying to properly support reordering.

Inside `moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath` I respond to the reordering by updating an `order` value on the `NSManagedObject`s and save the context like this:

```
[self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

So now all objects have the correct `order` value and the results controller's `NSFetchRequest` sorts by that value correctly.

This does appear to work, however when I scroll up and down in the table view, the old values are being displayed.  So it looks like when I use `objectAtIndexPath` on the `NSFetchedResultsController`, it doesn't return the latest object.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  // ... cell generation code ...

  NSManagedObject *obj = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  [cell.textLabel setText:sideEffect.name];

}
```

If I navigate away and then return, the cells are in the correct order.

After my call to `save`, do I need to:

- Refresh the `NSFetchedResultsController`
- Invalidate a cache
- Refresh/reset something on the `UITableView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to reinitialise the fetch controller after the move modifications had taken place.  Since I had a special getter method generating the controller (and performing the first fetch), I could just set the instance variable to `nil` to cause it to be regenerated next time it was needed.